# Sens : « par là-dessus » (Messieurs les Ronds-de-Cuir, Georges Courteline)

Tags: sens, expressions

> Le visage barbouillé d’une couche de craie, le nez entièrement habillé d’une carapace de pains à cacheter écarlates, ses cheveux, qu’il portait longs, ramenés par là-dessus à coups
> de brosse et tombant en mèches éplorées sur des yeux qui se mouvaient, blancs, entre les
> retroussis affreux de deux sanguinolentes paupières, il vint s’accroupir près de la porte, de façon que Soupe, à son retour, restât cloué d’épouvante sur le seuil, au vu de cette face de vampire.

Que signifie « ramenés par là-dessus » dans le texte ci-dessus ?

Answer (score 2):

Cela signifie que ses cheveux tombent ou se trouvent au-dessus de son visage et de son nez, plutôt que de tomber sur les côtés ou l'arrière de sa tête, cela étant le résultat des *coups de brosse*.